# Unable to boot on old PC from Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, mbr

An old PC (MSI P6NGM, Intel Quad Core, 4GB RAM) is unable to boot into Windows 11 installed on a SSD (MBR). The BIOS says, that operating windows cannot be found. I have made sure, that correct bootable devices are set in BIOS. Windows was installed from an USB, that was created by Rufus.

The Windows 11 installation is working and it should really be a bootable MBR. There is a workaround how to get into that Windows - by booting into Windows 11 Setup from the USB, which "sees" the installed Windows and offers an option to load it. Which works - by this process I am able to use Windows without any issues.

From recovery console, I have tried to run these basic fixboot commands:

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL /force /mbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
sfc /scannow
```

All commands ended up sucessfully, apart from "bootrec /fixboot", which failed on "Access denied" error.

I have also tried an automatic Start-up Repair, however that failed. Details should have been logged in `%WIN%\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTail.txt`, but according to that logfile, all tests ended up successfully:

```
...
Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Boot status test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Root cause found: 
---------------------------
Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully.

---------------------------
---------------------------
```

According to DISKPART, the volume is bootable

```
DISKPART> LIST VOLUME

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 2     C   Kingston SS  NTFS   Partition    111 GB  Healthy    Boot
```

How to fix the Windows boot, so the PC can boot directly into it, without using any additional installation media?

Comment: Windows 11 cannot be booted from MBR only GPT with CSM disabled, what you are trying to do, is impossible

Comment: Was hoping for some possible "tweaks". Well at least there is a workaround using the Windows Setup media (and possibly other alternative bootloaders)

Comment: It’s impossible to boot Windows 11 from a disk that is formatted as MBR, it only supports GPT, which means UEFI mode and CSM must be disabled to accomplish that. What you want is impossible, tweaks to accomplish what you want do not exist, why can’t you boot with CSM disabled? It’s certainly old enough to support it.

Comment: It's a 2008 motherboard, it doesn't have UEFI

Comment: That is too old to boot into Windows 11..  I added this too into my answer

Comment: @user10099 - That means it’s impossible to boot into Windows 11.

Comment: Absolutely.  And I have added that to my answer.

Comment: I know now. But since it is possible to boot a Windows 11 setup, install the Windows and RUN it really smoothly, I was really hoping to get it to the finish somehow

Comment: I think you are out of luck with something 15 or so years old. Booting into setup is very different than running the OS.

Comment: Found a way using bcdboot c:/windows /s c: /f BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 requires a Generation 8 or above CPU to run.

So natively what you want will not work.

There is a registry setting to allow Windows 11 to install and run on older machines, but the results may be unpredictable and are neither guaranteed nor supported.

It may even be that Windows 11 will not boot and/or run on your computer.

> It's a 2008 motherboard, it doesn't have UEFI

This is too old to boot into Windows 11 and no way (I know of) to force it.

[Windows 11 on unsupported machines](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-windows-11-unsupported-pc/)

> Then follow these steps: Press Windows + R on your keyboard to open
> the Run dialog and type regedit, then press Enter. The Registry Editor
> should open. ... Right-click the empty space on the right and select
> New, then DWORD (32-bit) Value. Enter
> AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU as the name and save it.

Comment: The requirements are already bypassed by the Rufus image. I have no problems with running the Windows. I have only problem with booting into it. Probably something with the MBR / boot loader.

Comment: I have a very old machine now back to Windows 10 in the basement as an instrumentation machine. It got me into Windows 11 but eventually could go no further. It may be that Windows 11 will just not run on your machine. I added that statement to my answer.

Comment: @user10099 Rufus CAN'T bypass the UEFI/GPT requirement, nothing can. What you want to do is impossible, get over it, and please accept this correct answer.